# Hera won't shutdown

Tags: release-hera, kernel, shutdown

I installed elementary a couple of weeks ago, and I noticed that when I clicked on shutdown in the menu, the screen would turn black, the system wouldn't respond and I would have to press the power button for the machine to be turned off.

After some digging I got into [this site](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/) for systemd debugging, tried everything and nothing really happend so it may be a Kernel bug.

How can I troubleshoot this? Some more digging got me thinking it could be my hardware drivers on the kernel, is there anyway to solve this? I'll post my hardware if it's any help.

- Ryzen 3 3200g
- Msi b450m pro-m2 max
- 2x8gb T-Force 3200mhz ram
- 480gb WD SSD
- Evga 500w
- Grub dualboot Windows10

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors shows command in terminal: sudo update-initramfs -u? Can you paste them into pastebin and provide a link to your paste?

Comment: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hCbyKNxp) @Sysadmin

Comment: Thanks I will look for the firmware and provide a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

How to upgrade Elementary OS to the newest kernel.

Install necessary packages

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libncurses-dev bison flex libssl-dev libelf-dev
```

To check hardware

```
sudo lspci
```

To check missing firmware

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Make directories for firmware and kernel

```
mkdir /home/username/Downloads/amdgpu
mkdir /home/username/Downloads/kernel
```

To get rid of missing firmware errors for amdgpu

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega20_ta.bin for module amdgpu ####
```

Download amdgpu

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/amdgpu
wget https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries/files/4124959/firmware-radeon-ucode-rock_2.110_all.deb.zip
unzip firmware-radeon-ucode-rock_2.110_all.deb.zip
sudo dpkg -i firmware-radeon-ucode-rock_2.110_all.deb
```

Source: https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries/issues/82

Download kernel 5.7.0

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/kernel
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.7.tar.xz
tar -xf linux-5.7.tar.xz
cd linux-5.7
cp -v /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
make menuconfig
```

save config and then exit -> See source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

Then you have to chosee between make -j 4 or make -j - explanation below

use 4 core/thread - if your processor have 4 cores

```
make -j 4
```

use 8 core/thread - if your processor have 8 cores

```
make -j 8
```

Install modules

```
sudo make modules_install
```

compile the kernel

```
sudo make install
```

Update init ram and filesystem

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.7.0
```

ignore these errors below, just because those three bin files are not made yet

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_dmcu.bin for module amdgpu
```

Update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart computer

```
sudo reboot
```

Check the kernel version

```
uname -mrs
```

To check missing firmware after compilation of new kernel

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

to check errors after reboot:

```
sudo journalctl -b
sudo dmesg
```